# Had to reinstall windows and want to use my first xampp install

Tags: xampp, multiple-versions

I've reset my Windows 10 and it lost all my applications but my data is intact. I still have my original xampp folder and need to obviously reinstall xampp but I want to use all my database settings from my first install. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Just install xampp and replace the configuration files, as in, replace the new `my.cnf` with the old `my.cnf`. This should solve your problem.